# How to Enable Ubuntu KDE Dolphin to Preview Audio Thumbnails?

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, kde, dolphin

I've noticed that Ubuntu 16.04 running KDE's Dolphin file manager is not able to preview audio thumbnails for some reason. I'm not certain why, and I've checked the Configure Dolphin -> General -> Previews -> File Types, and Audio is not listed as a supported type (It doesn't appear at all) Is there some way I can fix this? I interact with audio and am religious about tagging them with pictures and it kind of sucks not being able to see the thumbnails.

Note: I've seen https://www.linux-apps.com/content/show.php?content=114885, but a lot of people were saying that it didn't work, and it doesn't appear to be the same version of KDE that I'm running.

Edit 0: After following the `cmake` instructions, I got this error wen trying to run `make`:
[image: make command]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**KDE preview thumbnail**

The KDE applications can show a thumbnail for a file if there is a thumb creator plugin installed for the file type. After installation the plugin need to be enabled from the application settings.

**KDE Frameworks 5 / Plasma 5 / Applications**

Current KDE is released as three projects: Frameworks, Plasma and KDE Application. Release schedules: https://community.kde.org/Schedules

Application and the Framework version can be looked at the application help. With the Dolphin: Dolphin > Control > Help > About Dolphin:

[image]

**Audio thumbnailers**

KDE4: https://www.linux-apps.com/content/show.php?content=114885

KF5 (KDE Frameworks 5):

- https://github.com/eplightning/audiothumbs-frameworks
- https://store.kde.org/p/1155023/

A build example with the Debian based: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?t=32568&page=5&p=390275&viewfull=1#post390275

**Copy of the build/installation example:**

Downloading the audiothumbs-frameworks-master.zip

audiothumbs-frameworks: https://github.com/eplightning/audiothumbs-frameworks

[image]

Unpacking the audiothumbs-frameworks-master.zip

Installing build dependencies:

- build-essential
- cmake
- extra-cmake-modules
- kio-dev
- libflac++-dev
- libtag1-dev

Compiling and installing:

Generic commands:

```
mkdir -p builddir
cd builddir && cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(kf5-config --prefix) -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DKDE_INSTALL_USE_QT_SYS_PATHS=ON
make
sudo make install
```

Example:

```
$ mkdir -p builddir


$ cd builddir && cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(kf5-config --prefix) -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DKDE_INSTALL_USE_QT_SYS_PATHS=ON
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for __GLIBC__
-- Looking for __GLIBC__ - found
-- Performing Test _OFFT_IS_64BIT
-- Performing Test _OFFT_IS_64BIT - Success
-- TagLib found: -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -ltag
-- FLAC++ found: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libFLAC++.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so
-- Performing Test FLAC_STREAMMETADATA_OPERATOR_FOUND
-- Performing Test FLAC_STREAMMETADATA_OPERATOR_FOUND - Success
-- Performing Test FLAC_METADATA_PICTURE_FOUND
-- Performing Test FLAC_METADATA_PICTURE_FOUND - Success
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/rog131/tmp/audiothumbs-frameworks-master/builddir


$ make
Scanning dependencies of target AudioThumbs_automoc
[ 25%] Automatic moc for target AudioThumbs
Generating moc_AudioThumbs.cpp
[ 25%] Built target AudioThumbs_automoc
Scanning dependencies of target AudioThumbs
[ 50%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/AudioThumbs.dir/AudioThumbs.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/AudioThumbs.dir/AudioThumbs_automoc.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX shared module AudioThumbs.so
[100%] Built target AudioThumbs

$ sudo make install                                                                  
[ 25%] Automatic moc for target AudioThumbs
[ 25%] Built target AudioThumbs_automoc
[100%] Built target AudioThumbs
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Installing: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/AudioThumbs.so
-- Installing: /usr/share/kservices5/AudioThumbs.desktop
```

**Part of the official KDE release:**

The audio thumbnailer is released as part of the KDE Applications 17.04 or later: https://git.reviewboard.kde.org/r/129985/ .

Audio thumbnailer is part of the kio-extras. Ubuntu packages: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kio-extras&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

**Possible backported packages**

Kubuntu is offering backports: http://www.kubuntu.org -> http://www.kubuntu.org/news/

[image]

Comment: Maybe I'm not well versed, but I can't figure out what to do after I download the zip from github. There are uncompiled C files there and the Readme is rather vague. As far as instructions, what should I do? Is there a PPA I can add? Should I compile and run the C file from the github repository?

Comment: Did you read the compilation example ? Installed the needed files ? Tried the commands ?

Comment: I got an error after running the `make` command. `cmake went just fine though.

Comment: Your error message has: 'fatal error: QObject: No such file or directory'. Do you have the package : qtbase5-dev installed ?

Comment: The package is updated with taglib1.11 dependency, which is not in ubuntu 16.04. compiling taglib didn't help

Comment: taglib1.11 has been backported to xenial. Updated instruction is here https://github.com/bvbfan/Audio-thumbs