# Audio preview in Dolphin Kubuntu 17.04

Tags: sound, kubuntu, 17.04, dolphin, thumbnails

Dolphin is not displaying previews for audio files in Kubuntu 17.04.

Acconding to https://askubuntu.com/a/918342/35245 :

> Audio thumbnailer is part of the kio-extras.

And according to https://store.kde.org/p/1155023 :

> Audio Thumbs will be part of kio-extras 17.04, so when you on 17.04
>   release you don't need to do this [download and compile] anymore.

kio-extras is installed, and in case it is meaningful this file is installed:

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kfileaudiopreview.so

But I can't see any "Audio file" check option in Dolphin > Preferences > Previews.

On the other hand I do can see "ffmpegthumbs" videos option, but can't understand why it doesn't take charge of it, as renaming extensions from "m4a" to "mp4" does the job and displays the audio cover.

Comment: Do you install 'totem' package ? It's may be helpful

Comment: You will need KDE Applications 17.04. The Kubuntu 17.04 was released with the KDE Applications 16.12.3: https://kubuntu.org/news/kubuntu-17-04-released/ . The Kubuntu project may release backports - announcements are released at the https://kubuntu.org/news/

Comment: I think it is badly named in Dolphin and leads to confusion among users, it should not be called "audio preview" but "audio cover" or something similar. Audio preview I understand that is when you hover the mouse over the icon and it starts to sound automatically. The same could be said of videos, one thing is a video thumbnail and another thing is a video preview, where if you hover your mouse over a file a small video should be played.