# Can Dolphin Display Local Album Art Thumbnails?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, music, dolphin

I have a more specific version of ([How to Enable Ubuntu KDE Dolphin to Preview Audio Thumbnails?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/918295/how-to-enable-ubuntu-kde-dolphin-to-preview-audio-thumbnails)). Can Dolphin display local album art? In other words, album art attached to the file itself instead of an an online store? I tend towards having a lot of locally stored album art.

NOTE: I've followed the tutorial in the above question, but for my local album art files, no image is displayed.